# The less our representatives

Tags: meaning

What does "parochial" mean? less describe which part?
**The less our representatives** are bound to the demands of nationhood, the less **parochial** their outlook is likely to be.

Comment: See http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/parochial

Comment: You have asked a number of questions about the meaning of this word. Whenever you ask a question, you should describe what issue is confusing you and explain what you already have learned from doing research (like looking in a dictionary). This question (and your other questions) would be better if you wrote a few sentences like "Dictionary X says that "parochial" can mean a, b or c. This seems similar to definition a, but I think it doesn't quite fit because [insert reason]."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it means "Narrow in outlook " .
Please lookup it in dictionary.